# How can I get IIS to publish cache headers for my favicon.ico?

Tags: iis, caching, http-headers, favicon

Our site's favicon.ico file hasn't changed in years - and isn't going to change any time soon - so I'd like to configure IIS to serve it with a far-future cache expiry header. The rest of the content in the root folder of my site is dynamic pages that shouldn't be cached - but as far as I can tell, IIS only allows you to set content expiry cache on a per-folder basis - so is there any way to set a cache header for favicon.ico without affecting the rest of the content in the home directory as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep - drill down to the file.

In IIS Manager (on IIS6), navigate to the file, right click, properties, HTTP Headers tab, check Enable Content Expiration; party on with the other settings.

Kudos to Dylan (below) for IIS7 instructions and this snippet.

This creates the following section in web.config, so you can probably achieve the same thing just by editing the file directly.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="favicon.ico">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="90.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Awesome. One point - I couldn't right-click the file and view Properties, but after highlighting it in the Content View, the favicon.ico appeared in the left-hand nav tree and I was then able to highlight it and click the "HTTP Response Headers" icon just as I can on regular folders. 

In IIS7 the configuration is stored in web.config so I've added the XML snippet that's actually created by this process to the answer.

Comment: It's a version thing then. My 'proper' server is IIS6 so that's where I verified my approach. My Win7 laptop has IIS7 and your approach worked. I found an extra slight twist - after highlighting in Content View, and finding that there were no properties - I saw the alert message saying I had to move to the Features View. Once there, like you, it was in the left hand tree view. Edited answer.

Comment: I update my web.config file with this snippet and by looking at YSlow, it is still appearing as (no expires). I'm using IIS 7.